# Android Facebook SDK: How to generate a non-debug hash key?

Tags: android, facebook

So, I know how to generate the debug hash key with the password of android.  I know that for each new device, I need to generate (and upload to facebook) the new hash key.

Now, I am not yet ready to actually be in production, but I'd like to distribute the app to a set of testers that would prefer not to generate hash things on their own.  I see references to a non debug hash key:

> Next, you will need to generate a Key Hash for the application. For
>   debugging, if using Eclipse, you will want to generate this Key Hash
>   using the Android debug key. When you are ready to publish your app,
>   you will need to generate a Key Hash for your signing keys and update
>   this value in Facebook before your signed app will work.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/integrate-facebook-logins-in-your-android-app/296

How do you generate this? I've never made a production (signed) app before, is this something to do with that?  Is there a downside to signing my app before its done?  If it's not, what do I do to let any device run this app with facebook connectivity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily generate an own key to sign your application in release mode. See the Android documentation for detailed information: [Signing in Release Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Keystore generation example:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
  -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then generate the hash for Facebook as you did with the debug key:

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And finally share your signed apk with your group of testers, that's all.

Comment: thanks! man, signing the app is more complicated than I thought, but I have to learn it sometime anyways, so may as well be now

Comment: @ottel142  SSO is worked perfectly. But when I signed my build, and make release hash key using above method, my SSO fails

Comment: @ottel142 Do I need to generate a hashkey everytime I make an update to my app (i.e. I make a new release apk) ?

Comment: @Want All of your release APKs have to be signed with the same keystore, this is how Google/Android validates you as the developer of the app. The Android Package Manager refuses to install updates signed with a different keystore. So because the key doesn't change, the hash also stays the same.

Comment: @ottel142 Well, I generated the key hash with my keystore and sometimes it works perfectly (login with fb) and sometimes it says Invalid key hash.. I don't know what to do :/ Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Want Maybe you're sometimes testing with the debug build? Debug builds are signed with a different keystore...

Comment: @ottel142 Yes! My teammate and I are working in parralel on a project that involves FB Login, so do we need to have 1 release key hash and 2 debug key hashes or do we need to sign the app in release version on each build? Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: @Want I prefer to generate a app-debug.keystore. Then use this one to override the default debug keystore (in build.gradle -> signingConfigs.debug.storeFile) and check it into version control. So after this all team members use the same debug keystore.