# Adding hash key to Facebook Key Hashes

Tags: facebook, cordova

I have signed an app with phonegap build and I am using FB connect but once I try to login, Facebook sends back a message Invalid key hash. *The key hash ### does not match any stored key hashes*. However when I try to add the key hash on the Facebook Developer page the hash key is not being validated in the textfield. If I however add one extra letter to the hash it's validated and it receives the blue css label with the X mark. Any idea why the hash is not validated?

Thanks!

Comment: I had to follow these steps to generate a valid key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634159/andriod-facebook-sdk-how-to-generate-a-non-debug-hash-key

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/17732453#17732453

Answer (score 3):

Here is this beautiful trick:

The key hash ### does not match any stored key hashes. Just add = after the key which is being shown by the facbook app. In this case it is ###=

You are done!!